# How does openvpn's redirect-gateway option work?

Tags: routing, openvpn

I have a simple openvpn setup with the client running with a `redirect-gateway def1` option.

Here's the resulting routing table (VPN_SERVER_IP is the public IP of the VPN server, local network is 192.168.127.0/24 and VPN LAN is 10.8.0.0/24):

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.0.49       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun_tcpdec
0.0.0.0         192.168.127.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.49       255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun_tcpdec
10.8.0.49       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun_tcpdec
VPN_SERVER_IP   192.168.127.1   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.49       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun_tcpdec
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
192.168.127.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

It works and all the traffic is redirected to the VPN, but I don't understand how.
Suppose I try to ping Cloudflare's DNS at 1.1.1.1, shouldn't the second  rule just send the packets through the router (rule 2)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Traffic flows via your VPN, because the traffic matches either of these two rules:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.8.0.49       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun_tcpdec
128.0.0.0       10.8.0.49       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun_tcpdec
```

The `redirect-gateway def1` option adds these two routes. These routes are used for forwarding traffic instead of the second rule, because these rules are more specific (netmask has one bit set, in second rule netmask has zero bits set).

This means that approximately half of the internet is forwarded with the first rule and second half of the internet is forwarded with the second rule.

This approach is used because it works on most platforms. An alternative would be to use routing table entry priorities, where the default route assigned by OpenVPN would get higher priority than the other default gateway.